# Entity Framework Core auto value generation of 'last modified' column with data annotations and Postgresql

Tags: windows, entity-framework-core, npgsql, .net-7.0, postgresql-15

I'm using .NET 7 with Entity Framework Core and postgresql (npgsql).

I want to add autogenerated `CreateOn` and `ModifiedOn` columns to all my tables. I want them to update to the current datetime when a row is inserted or updated respectively.

So my models all inherit an abstract class with that has two, data annotated, columns.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTimeOffset UpdatedDate { get; set; }
```

I assumed, like it says in the .NET docs, this would autogenerate datetime when a row is inserted and updated. However, this autogeneration isn't shown in the migration, and when seeding the database I get an error

> null is not an acceptable value for createdDate

(which I leave blank when seeding because it's supposed to be autogenerated). To me this means that autogeneration isn't working.

Online resources tell me to add the following line to the `DbContext` `OnModelCreate` function to autogenerate:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EamEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.CreatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("NOW()");

modelBuilder.Entity<EamEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.UpdatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("NOW()");
```

This seems to work (I've only tried inserting), however, this isn't a feasible because I have many tables that each have these datetime columns, meaning I'd have to do this for each column.

This makes me think that I'm missing something. Is there a solution that just makes data annotations work?? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While you can define a default value for insertion (as you've done above), the same doesn't work for updating; [see the documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/generated-properties.html#timestamp-generation) for more details.

To apply configuration to many properties in bulk, see [model bulk configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/bulk-configuration#bulk-configuration-in-onmodelcreating) in the EF documentation.